# how to password protect posts in wordpress using php

Tags: wordpress

I'm having a little trouble trying to find any info on this..

I want to password protect a post in Wordpress. I know I can quick edit a page and enter a password, but is there a way to set a page as protected & add password with php?

The idea is to build a simple custom login page with Username/password that uses the standard protected posts functionality that I can set up in the admins 'edit page'.

The username for each post is stored as custom metadata set in the login page.. So you'd have username as the key and the posts ID as the value, I'll then re-direct the user to the protected post with that ID.